# Map with nearby point of interests like dat-trucker app

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, google-places-api

This might not looks like a real question, but I have a use-case for which I am not able to find the solutions. I have to show few `point of interests` like 'walmart','truck wash', 'rest-area' etc. My problem is Google Places map API doesn't give the filter option on the nearby searches and mapkit `MKLocalSearch` returns data beyound the bound region. My requirement is same like the Dat-trucker app. I am wondering, how they are showing "POI" on their maps. Seems like they are using MapKit, cause there is no attribution for google.Is there any `alternative for Google Places API` which can return the nearby places with filter functionality. I am attaching screenshot of the reference app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can give the [Yep Fusion API](https://www.yelp.com/developers) a try. They provide nearby businesses which is what the Google Places API does.